# Convert Hex to Binary at android

Tags: android, binary, hex

I used this code for converts hex to binary but works only with 8 bits.How can i expand to 16bits?For example i want to convert FFFF to 1111111111111111 ....also i need to fill the zero 0...

```
 void HexToBinary1(String Hex) {

    int i = Integer.parseInt(Hex, 16);//16 bits
    String Bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);//Converts int to binary

    String Bin2="";
    if(Bin.length()==8){Bin2=Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==7){Bin2="0"+Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==6){Bin2="00"+Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==5){Bin2="000"+Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==4){Bin2="0000"+Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==3){Bin2="00000"+Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==2){Bin2="000000"+Bin;}
    if(Bin.length()==1){Bin2="0000000"+Bin;}

    text1.setText(Bin2);//Shows binary
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
String HexToBinary(String Hex) {
        String bin =  new BigInteger(Hex, 16).toString(2);
        int inb = Integer.parseInt(bin);
        bin = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%08d", inb);
        return bin;
}
```

It will return binary string as 8 digit format.

Comment: After needs Integer.toBinaryString?How can i convert my code?

Comment: good...work but only with small 0005 but for ffff i have errors

Comment: Needs Long instead integer?

Comment: @user2342687 just use %016d instead of %08 d... it is a formatter arguement

Comment: Thanks!!! String bin = new BigInteger(Hex, 16).toString(2);
     long inb = Long.parseLong(bin);
        bin = String.format("%016d",inb);

Answer (score 2):

you need to tell Java that the int is in hex, like this:

```
String HexToBinary(String Hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(Hex, 16);
    String Bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    return Bin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static String getBits(double value)
{
    //get bit-string of double
    String printString = (Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value)));

    //add leading zeros if bitstring is shorter than 64 bits
    while (printString.length() < 64)
        printString = "0" + printString;

    //format string by adding byte padding
    StringBuilder bitwise = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
        bitwise.append(printString.substring(i*8, (i+1)*8)+" ");

    return bitwise.toString();
}
```

Feel free to further adapt for ints and add in the feature of parsing a HEX string.